# Why can't I use gcsfuse command on a Google Instance with GPU and preinstalled TF and more?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

My goal is to mount a Google Storage bucket in my Google Compute instance machine.

I created a Google Compute Instance of type

> c2-deeplearning-tf-1-14-cu100

It came with various libraries preinstalled, among others CUDA, CuDNN, TensorFlow, and (Python's) GCFSs. 
After creating it, I followed the [instructions for installation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md) of `gcsfuse` command. No errors were thrown. However, upon any attempt at using `gcsfuse` command in bash I'm getting the following error:

```
: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gcsfuse", line 7, in <module>
    from gcsfs.cli.gcsfuse import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gcsfs/cli/gcsfuse.py", line 3, in <module>
    from fuse import FUSE
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fuse/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .defect_augment import DefectAugment
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fuse/defect_augment.py", line 11, in <module>
    from gunpowder import BatchFilter
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunpowder/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import nodes
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunpowder/nodes/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .add_affinities import AddAffinities
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunpowder/nodes/add_affinities.py", line 6, in <module>
    from gunpowder.ext import malis
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunpowder/ext/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    import augment
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/augment.py", line 181, in <module>
    def _surround(aux_fn, around=False, before=False, after=False):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/augment.py", line 130, in decorator
    allargs, fn_name = _get_args_and_name(fn)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/augment.py", line 37, in _get_args_and_name
    code = fn.func_code
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'func_code'
```

It appears not only when I'm trying to mount any bucket in my machine, but even upon calling `gcsfuse --help`.

My guess is, because the error is clearly Pythonic and not Go-like, maybe the preinstalled Python GCSFs somehow corrupted here. However, according to the [documentation](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), the GCSFs also should enable using the bash `gcsfuse` command.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/331 may be of interest.  Users reported success qualifying the full path `/usr/bin/gcsfuse`.